# Redis read all values for all hashes

Tags: java, spring, redis

I use this method for Reading all values from Redis, but I am not sure if this is good way:

```
public List<Value> findAll() {

        Set<String> allAvailableKeys = redisTemplate.keys("*");
        List<Value> valuesList = new ArrayList<Value>();

        Iterator<String> itr = allAvailableKeys.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String id = itr.next();

            try {
                Value value = (Value) hashOperations.get(id, id);
                valuesList.add(value);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                // cache could expire in meantime
            }
        }

        return valuesList;
```

Comment: You should replace `keys` with `scan` keys can return a very long list of keys.

Comment: BTW, do you really need find all values or do post filter according to the values?